# Acces Angular JS Local Storage outside of Angular JS on Single Page Applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, local-storage, single-page-application

Say you use local storage of Angular JS.

https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

How do you access this data WITHOUT Angular JS.

You can use standard JavaScript or some other JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular JS does not have it's own local storage, it uses the browsers local storage.
You can acces this with plain javascript

for example:

```
var taste = localStorage.getItem('favoriteflavor');
```

or

```
localStorage.setItem('favoriteflavor','vanilla');
```

examples taken from:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

Check with caniuse.com regarding browser support for local storage API. 
With browser support you can access it from `window.localStorage` - The angular library is just  a wrapper around this with probably a fall back method.